# MySQL Timezone Query

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I got two fields : `time_scan_start` and `time_scan_end` (timestamp field).

When I open my connection to MySQL with PDO, I use `SET NAMES utf8,time_zone = "+0:00";`.

Now, when I do a query in MySQL, do I have to use UTC time `WHERE time_scan_start >= UTC` or I need to use the PHP local zone ? Will MySQL do the ajustements it self ?

I did some test with gmdate and date, sometime it work, other it don't.

Thanks

Comment: a standard mysql time string has no TZ data, so doing `time_scan_start >= '2012-11-02 03:04:05'` will assume the timezones all match up and just do a direct comparison of the values. tz stuff only enters into play when you're doing conversions/formatting involving tz values.

Comment: @MarcB Ok, thanks ! So whatever I put in the WHERE, it's going to search assuming the WHERE date is ok and suppose to be in UTC (if MySQL is setup as UTC +00:00) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comparing against `TIMESTAMP` fields, you need to use comparison values in the timezone of the server. You can determine the server timezone via:

```
SELECT @@time_zone;
```

Therefore, if you've executed

```
SET NAMES time_zone = "+0:00";
```

then you will use UTC-based values.

This is because `TIMESTAMP` fields are stored in MySQL in UTC, and are converted to the server's timezone before display (or a comparison).

Note: if you are comparing against `DATETIME` fields or `TIME` fields, you will need to use a comparision value in the same timezone as was used when the value was inserted into the field.

This is because `DATETIME` and `TIME` fields are stored in MySQL without any timezone information, and are not converted before display (or a comparison).

Answer (score 2):

MySQL `DATETIME` knows nothing of timezone. So you need to **decide which timezone will be your "default"** (usually UTC) and store all your timestamps using that timezone, using `CONVERT_TZ` if necessary.

Then, do the same for the search, i.e. convert the values to UTC before using them in the search.